# Interesting Olympiad Questions.

Tags: soft-question, contest-math

Rather than through research, I much prefer discovering new maths or interesting theories through doing problems and I also enjoy contest maths which has led me to this question:

Which (high school) Olympiad questions lead into or borrow from higher level mathematics? Any examples that point to interesting theories or results?

Comment: One of the issues you will find with most Olympiad questions is that they are supposed to be accessible with high school maths. For most such questions the higher level will arise, if at all, from putting a particular question in a more general mathematical context.

Comment: @MarkBennet, maybe 'higher maths' wasn't the best turn of phrase. I am not expecting graduate level results from Olympiads. Anything that leads to interesting results or theorems would be welcome as well. I've edited my question slightly.

Answer (score 9):

One of my favorite "gateway problems" is from the 2001 Bay Area Mathematics Olympiad:

> Let $a_n$ be the number of permutations $\tau$ on $n$ letters such that $\tau \circ \tau \circ \tau$ is the identity.  Prove that $3^{334}$ divides $a_{2001}$.

This is the question that originally got me interested in $p$-adic analysis.

The "high level" approach is to observe that the exponential generating function of $\{a_n\}$ is $e^{x + \frac{1}{3}x^3}$.  To (asymptotically) count the number of powers of $3$ dividing $a_n$, it is enough to compare the $3$-adic radius of convergence of $e^{x + \frac{1}{3}x^3}$ with that of $e^{x}$.

This is a nice way to start thinking about the Artin-Hasse exponential $e^{x + \frac{1}{p}x^p + \frac{1}{p^2}x^{p^2} + \cdots}$, and it leads naturally to research-level questions about non-archimedean analytic continuations, among other things.